# Windows Explorer unresponsive - Hard DIsk causing error

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer

I recently uninstalled a game from my 'E' drive, in order to reinstall it. After the download for the game files that were writing to my E Drive seemed to not be working, I decided to reboot my machine by using the start menu shortcut for rebooting.
After waiting about 5 minutes of the machine not restarting, I went over and hard-restarted the machine with the power button.

When I logged back onto Windows10 the system was very laggy. Windows Explorer was no longer responsive and the Taskbar was missing. Eventually Explorer allowed me to look at some of my drives and I noticed that the E drive had lost its name.

The next thing I did to investigate the issue was to right click on 'This PC' and choose 'Manage' then navigated to 'Disk Management'. From there I could see that the E Drive was still missing its name (the Drive letter was still assigned, but the original name was missing). The description of the drive said that it is Healthy Partition, BUT it now says that the filesystem **RAW.**

From [this](https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/ssd-shows-raw-partition#:%7E:text=When%20you%20see%20a%20RAW,may%20also%20report%20as%20RAW.) site:

> "There are lots of things which could potentially cause data to become
> corrupted on a drive. One of the most common culprits is loss of power
> to a drive while new data is being written"

This sounds a lot like what happened to my drive.

Next I ran a CMD window and ran SFC/scannow. The result of this scan was this:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully
> repaired them. For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log
> file located at windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example
> C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline repairs, details are included
> in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

I don't really know what to look for in this log file, but the majority of it is comprised of repeats (hundreds of iterations) of this message:

> Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package
> Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-nn-no-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.1,
> applicable state: Installed

I have uploaded a copy of the log file [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WFvXdyyr70DwPhaUiq3D-KPIIJ3hD30V/view?usp=sharing) if anyone wants to look at it (its much too large to paste here or at PasteBin).

I also ran this command to get Windows to show me the results of the SFC scan:

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"
```

This created a file named `sfcdetails.txt` on the desktop. There are various iterations of the same output here:

> 2024-01-14 19:32:31, Info                  CSI    000001af [SR]
> Beginning Verify and Repair transaction 2024-01-14 19:32:31, Info
> CSI    000001b0 [SR] Verify complete

So at this point I am unsure of what is happening exactly (I suspect it is something to do with the E Drive). Explorer eventually starts working, and other things that are normal startup items that usually load instantly at start up eventually load.

Running Winows10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: RaW partition means any file store on the device is lost. The corrupted system file isn’t vital.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you,  I understand. I tried formatting the drive from Explorer and from Disk Management which both produce the message of not being able to format. Also, if I use the 'Delete Volume' option from Disk Management I get the error 'The request could not be performed  because of an I/O device error'.

Comment: The drive might be failing, or you might just have a dodgy SATA connection. Testing the SATA is far cheaper to start with. Run a new cable after cleaning the contacts with a good contact cleaner spray [power off, of course]. Make sure there are no sharp bends on the cable & zero tension on the plugs/sockets.

Comment: For most disks that became RAW, this is a sign of failure.

Comment: @harrymc - I've had it happen. I did lose the data on the drive, but not the drive which was perfectly happy once the SATA was sound. [Solidly backed up so I put little effort into recovery, just wiped, tested, restored, put it back in service]

Comment: @Tetsujin: This is possible, but I'll never fully trust such a drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin were you able to restore the data on the drive after it went RAW, or did you restore it from a backup on another disk?

Comment: I just restored from backup.